# why is this an Infinite loop

Tags: python, list, loops, while-loop

I cant quite work out why this is an infinite loop:

```
while hold<=3:
    if a[hold] in num:
            cows==cows+1
            hold==hold+1
            continue
    else:
            hold==hold+1
            continue
```

If anyone could offer corrections it would be really helpful!

Comment: it should be `hold = hold + 1`. Only a single = sign

Comment: `hold==hold+1` is a boolean expression, which evaluates as False or 0 so is <3

Answer (score 3):

```
hold==hold+1
```

This is an evaluation statement, not assignment.

Answer (score 2):

Use one "=" instead of "==", two == is just comparing it doesn't chage hold variable

Answer (score 1):

You're never making assignment, just comparaison :

```
while hold<=3:
    if a[hold] in num:
            cows=cows+1
            hold=hold+1
            continue
    else:
            hold=hold+1
            continue
```